# How does ZF2 event-manager allow for aspect-oriented programming?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Quote from [ZF2 event manager doc](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html):

The EventManager is a component designed for the following use cases:

- Implementing simple subject/observer patterns.
- Implementing Aspect-Oriented designs.
- Implementing event-driven architectures.

I'm confused about "aspect-oriented" part of it. I always thought that with aspect oriented programming "weaving" requires compile stage which PHP doesn't have or injecting aspects into generated cached files as flow3 does (thus not touching your app code).

What does ZF2 mean by "event manager allows for aspect-oriented programming" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be they think of events like aspects? While all framework object interaction done with event *using single event manager* it's possible to inject you code into all the interactions easy.

P.S. It's just a guess.

Comment: it's probably what they mean... Although - I'm hesitatn to call it AOP. For real AOP programming - this awesome PECL ash to be integrated into core I guess: https://github.com/AOP-PHP/AOP

Comment: There is aop module which have nice implementation: https://packagist.org/packages/dino/aop-module

Comment: I can't say for sure yet myself, but that sounds right Valera. I'm doing a lot of reading on it at the moment. So if I find some specifics, I'll drop a link here afterwards.

Comment: If you want to use real AOP with ZF2 without any extensions, have a look at Go! AOP library https://github.com/lisachenko/go-aop-php There is ready to use example for AOP in ZF2: https://github.com/lisachenko/zf2-aspect